# Magento, configurable products or simple products? what's best for SEO?

Tags: magento, seo, product, configurable

I’m new to Magento and I need a suggestion about configurable products. I made many test with configurable products and their attributes..surely it’s really interesting and help to keep clean categories. By the way, before create many configurable products, I’m asking myself if, for a customer that is searching for a product on google (for example), it will be more easy to find a configurable product or a simple product. For example take an E27 lamp bulb. I made a configurable product with warm white and cold white light colors attribute. The potential customer will search on google "e27 lamp bulb warm white".
The question is: The configurable product has more or less probability to be shown between search results instead of simple products? (naturally the simple product name will be: "e27 lamp bulb warm white" while the configurable product name will be: "e27 lamp bulb").
Do you suggest to make many simple products or simplify with configurable ones??
Many thanks to all who will reply, have a nice day.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO advice. Might be appropriate on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as SEO is concerned Simple products are better option.
But just to remind that we donot choose simple or configurable based on SEO but on our needs.
If we need to manage the inventories separately we create differnet simple products and assign to Configurable but if didnot need that the simple product with options is ok.